# $a_1<\ldots<a_n$ and $a_i-a_j \mid a_i$ for $i<j$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I know the answer of the following problem: I am posting it here just because I really like it and I want to share it with the community :)

Prove that there exists a positive costant $c$ such that for any positive integer $n$ and any sequence $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ of strictly increasing positive integers for which $a_i-a_j$ divides $a_i$ whenever $i<j$ then $a_1>n^{cn}$.

[Ps. As a preliminary step, you can also provide an example of such sequence, for any fixed $n$]

Comment: If you know the answer, put it, and label your answer as a community wiki.

Comment: Not. This is a serious question made by Erdos and used also in some Olympiads. After seeing here bunch of people asking help for their homeworks, I was hoping people could have fun on a really interesting one. If this is not the case, I will avoid it in future

Comment: I know where this comes from. This is why I asked the answer...